# Data corruption on the secondary peer of a MariaDB-Galera cluster, while the main peer is OK, so how to recover?

Tags: mariadb, galera

We have a Galera cluster of MariaDB databases, consisting of:

- `galera-4.x86_64 v26.4.9-1.el7.centos @mariadb`
- `MariaDB-server.x86_64 v10.5.12-1.el7.centos @mariadb`

The cluster has two nodes working in an active-active way, and the main node has more weight than the secondary node to break even during a network outage.

The recent vulnerability scanning includes simulated cyberattack, and the test caused failure on the `mariadbd` daemon. The main node failed to restart, and the secondary node's system log contains messages about data corruption.

We recovered the cluster by:

- first, re-bootstrapping the main node, and then
- restarting the secondary node with `innodb_force_recovery=1`, and then
- restarting the secondary node again with `innodb_force_recovery=1` removed from the configuration file.

The database cluster works OK, and we got successful results on testing transactions. However, `mysqlcheck` found corrupted index B-trees on the secondary node, while it shows OK on the main node.

**Our Question:**

- Considering the clustering context, what is the best way to fix the data corruption?
- What might be the causes of corruption, and how to prevent it in the future?
- Miscellaneously and optionally, if we want to troubleshoot similar issues by ourselves, how do we start learning the programming basics of this open-source project?

We are new to this area, and we highly appreciate hints, suggestions, and reference links.

**Details:**

The screenshot of `mysqlcheck` results on the secondary node.

```
-sh-4.2$ mysqlcheck --all-databases --verbose -u username -p
Enter password:
Processing databases
appdb
appdb.auth_group                              OK
appdb.auth_group_permissions                  OK
appdb.auth_permission                         OK
appdb.auth_user                               OK
appdb.auth_user_groups                        OK
appdb.auth_user_user_permissions              OK
appdb.authtoken_token                         OK
appdb.celery_taskmeta                         OK
appdb.celery_tasksetmeta                      OK
appdb.corsheaders_corsmodel                   OK
appdb.django_admin_log                        OK
appdb.django_content_type                     OK
appdb.django_migrations                       OK
appdb.django_session                          OK
appdb.django_site                             OK
appdb.djcelery_crontabschedule                OK
appdb.djcelery_intervalschedule               OK
appdb.djcelery_periodictask                   OK
appdb.djcelery_periodictasks                  OK
appdb.djcelery_taskstate                      OK
appdb.djcelery_workerstate                    OK
appdb.eav_attribute                           OK
appdb.eav_enumgroup                           OK
appdb.eav_enumgroup_enums                     OK
appdb.eav_enumvalue                           OK
appdb.eav_value                               OK
appdb.app_business                            OK
appdb.app_customer
Warning  : InnoDB: The B-tree of index PRIMARY is corrupted.
Warning  : InnoDB: The B-tree of index app_customer_transaction_id_2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxa_uniq is corrupted.
Warning  : InnoDB: The B-tree of index eb_transaction_id_2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxa_fk_app_transaction_id is corrupted.
error    : Corrupt
appdb.app_emailtemplate                       OK
appdb.app_ministry                            OK
appdb.app_orderitem                           OK
appdb.app_orderitemlog                        OK
appdb.app_product                             OK
appdb.app_producttemplate                     OK
appdb.app_producttemplateattribute            OK
appdb.app_transaction                         OK
appdb.app_transactionattribute                OK
appdb.app_userbusiness                        OK
information_schema
-sh-4.2$
```

Comment: "to break even during a network outage" -- you _cannot_ test for all forms of network outage without a third node.  You are asking for trouble.